# Android write to external storage(Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am facing a shitty problem. I can't seem to get my app write to external storage(or anywhere). The app is running on a Android 4.4.4 KitKat device with the known SD card issue. But other apps of mine(compiling against lower Android versions) can still write to external storage on this device.. I have set the correct permission. Can someone please answer how to fix this crap.

Stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/tb_Totaal.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Code:

```
File directoryFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
directoryFile.mkdirs();

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/text.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f.getPath());
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_external_storage"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permissions names are case sensitive. Try using:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

---

According to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission), you **do not** need to include `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as it is automatically obtained when you require the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`permission.

Comment: Thank you, totally looked over that, really got to take a break.